Moving numbers to the front in a sequence game - Combinatorics Problem
Here's the question: Given a sequence which contains the numbers $1$ through $8,$ a move consists of moving one of the numbers to the front of the sequence. For example, for the sequence $(1, 5, 8, 3, 6, 2, 7, 4),$ we can move the number $6$ to the front, which results in the sequence $(6, 1, 5, 8, 3, 2, 7, 4).$ (We can also choose to move the first number to the front, which does not change the sequence.)We want to turn a sequence into the sequence $(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)$ with a series of moves. For how many starting sequences does this take a minimum of exactly four moves?
I took a shot at this problem and kind of concluded that numbers that are behind greater numbers in the sequence eventually have to be moved to the front to get our desired sequence, and for there to be a minimum of exactly 4 moves to $(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)$ , we must have that $5,6,7,8$ are in order (not necessarily consecutively) and that the $1, 2, 3$, and $4$ are moved forward at some point. I'm not too sure what to do next, but I do know that looking at reverse moves could be helpful...

Why not try it for a smaller set?  Suppose you had the first five integers instead of the first eight, what's the answer then?   What about six?

You've made a good start! You've basically characterized those starting sequences that can be finished in at most $4$ moves. Can you count them? Then, can you use the same idea to count those starting sequences that can be finished in at most $3$ moves? The difference of those two counts should give you your answer.

The answer is $5 . 6 . 7 . 8 = 1680$.
This is because, as you noticed,  $5, 6, 7, 8$ must be in order (though not necessarily consecutive). Then,  $1$ can be distributed to  $5$ rooms (these are the squares:  $□5□6□7□8□$). Similarly,  $2, 3,4$ can be distributed to  $6,7$, and  $8 $ different rooms, respectively.
To see how to obtain  $(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8) $ from any distribution, consider the example  $(5, 2, 3, 6, 7, 1, 8, 4) $. The first move is to bring  $4 $ to the front. (Actually, the general strategy is to move the number  $(5-n)$ to the front on the  $n-$th move.) This gives us  $(4, 5, 2, 3, 6, 7, 1, 8) $. Then, for the second move, bring  $3 $ (note that  $5-2 = 3 $) to the front, resulting in  $(3, 4, 5, 2, 6, 7, 1, 8) $. Continuing this process, we obtain  $(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 8) $ and finally  $(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8) $ after the third and fourth moves.
More details: Let's consider the following question first:
1)For how many starting sequences does this take a minimum of exactly 1 move?
For the answer, $2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8$ must be in order, and $1$ must be in one of the squares $□2□3□4□5□6□7□8□$. Note that any change in the order of $2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8$ will require more than $1$ move. Thus, the answer to the question is $8$.
Now, let's consider the following question:
2)For how many starting sequences does this take a minimum of exactly 2 moves?
For the answer, $3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8$ must be in order, and $2$ must be in one of the squares $□3□4□5□6□7□8□$. After that, $1$ must be in one of the squares $□3□4□2□5□6□7□8□$ (assuming that 2 is placed between $4$ and $5$ ). Note that any change in the order of $3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8$ will require more than $2$ moves. Thus, the answer to this question is $8 * 7 = 56$.
Consider the same questions for $3$ and $4$.
